# How to import XML file into MSSQL with duplicate tags in the XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, import

I have a sales XML file in which every sale looks like this:

```
<Sale>
<Store>2725</Store>
<Station>2</Station>
<Date>01/03/2015 14:23:24</Date>
<SaleType>12</SaleType>
<SaleNumber>9213</SaleNumber>
<Tot>1060.00</Tot>
<LnQnt>2</LnQnt>
<Lines>
<Line>
<Code>20</Code>
<Price>480.00</Price>
<Qnt>1</Qnt>
<LnTot>480.00</LnTot>
</Line>
<Line>
<Code>20</Code>
<Price>580.00</Price>
<Qnt>1</Qnt>
<LnTot>580.00</LnTot>
</Line>
</Lines>
<payments>
<PayQnt>2</PayQnt>
<Pay>1^ 500.00^</Pay>
<Pay>4^ 560.00^</Pay>
</payments>
</Sale>
```

I import the payments data using the following syntax:

```
DECLARE @InputXML XML

SELECT @InputXML = CAST(x AS XML)
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Temp\Sales.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(x)

INSERT INTO temp_sales_payments 
SELECT row.value('(../Store)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)') Store
    ,row.value('(../Station)[1]', 'int') Station
    ,row.value('(../Date)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)') Date
    ,row.value('(../SaleType)[1]', 'int') SaleType
    ,row.value('(../SaleNumber)[1]', 'int') SaleNumber
    ,row.value('(PayQnt)[1]', 'int') PayQnt  
    ,row.value('(Pay)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)') Pay
FROM  @InputXML.nodes('Sales/Sale/payments') AS X(row);
```

As long as there is one  tag, everything works fine, but when there are 2  tags or more, as in the sample data, only the first payment is imported.

Any help will be most appriciated.

Thanks, Gilad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example XML doesn't match your nodes query, it is missing "Sales" in the XML, so I had to modify that part of query.

```
SELECT xmlData.a.value('(../Store)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)') AS Store
    ,xmlData.a.value('(../Station)[1]', 'int') AS Station
    ,xmlData.a.value('(../Date)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)') AS Date
    ,xmlData.a.value('(../SaleType)[1]', 'int') AS SaleType
    ,xmlData.a.value('(../SaleNumber)[1]', 'int') AS SaleNumber
    ,xmlData.a.value('(PayQnt)[1]', 'int') AS PayQnt  
    ,xmld.b.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(255)') AS Pay
FROM  @InputXML.nodes('Sale/payments') xmlData(a)
CROSS APPLY XMLDATA.a.nodes('Pay') AS xmld(b)
```

Comment: Thanks a LOT Dbloch! Solved it!